# Mule Anypoint Studio throws error when creating new mule project

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio

OS:Windows 10, 
AnypointStudio file under the C:\Anypoint Studio , 
Mule Server 3.8.3 EE , 
JDK JRE is OK.
When I creating new mule project, Building workspace has encountered problem. Studio is working on ubuntu in Virtualbox, but doesnt work on Win10. Where am i doing wrong ??
Problem Occured

[image]

**Anypoint Workspace .metadata-> .log file**

[image]

Comment: How have you installed Anypoint? The all in one package from Mulesoft or  by the plugin? Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Adrian thanx for your return, but i fixed this error. Because the language of my computer is Turkish and i was getting this error when i installed anypoint. I made the lang. of my computer in English and then I havent received this error anymore.